# Web API: returns file with appended exception informaion

Tags: c#, rest, http, asp.net-web-api

Pretty simple api method return plain csv file:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/export")]
public HttpResponseMessage Export(Request model)
{
    var file = //get file
    var fileResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(file)
    };
    fileResponse.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    fileResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
    return fileResponse;
}
```

But from time to time content of result file contains strange exception information: it returns file content, then appends error page content (plain html), then exception info:

```
column,column...
data,data...
...
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
... //Content of error page
</html>
<!-- 
[HttpException]: Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.SetHeader(String name, String value, Boolean replace)
   at System.Web.HttpHeaderCollection.Set(String name, String value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.Set(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallHeaders.AspNetResponseHeaders.set_Item(String key, String[] value)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.SetHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinHelpers.AppendHeaderUnmodified(IDictionary`2 headers, String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary.AppendValues(String key, String[] values)
   at Microsoft.Owin.ResponseCookieCollection.Append(String key, String value, CookieOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler.<ApplyResponseGrantAsync>d__b.MoveNext()
   ...
-->
```

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Try using `var fileResponse = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);` then setting the content property after.

Comment: No, the same result

Comment: Then i guess it is a middleware problem with owin. Are you using any custom middleware in your pipeline?